# "He gets awake " "He gets waken up"

Tags: idioms, expressions, american-english, phrases, british-english

As with can use "get" with both "an adjective" and 'past participle". SO can i say "He gets awake = he awakes. He gets woken up= he wakes up.

Answer (score 1):

### No

"He gets woken" does not mean "he wakes up" but rather "someone awakens him". "He gets awake" sounds wrong to a native speaker. It might possibly mean "He becomes awake" or "he wakes up" as in

> After the light shies on his face, he gets awake gradually.

but it is still a strained and unusual form, and i would strongly advise avoiding it.

> - he stays awake
> - he remains awake
> - he keeps awake

all mean much the same thing.

The word "gets" usually means "receives" as in "he gets a gift" or else it indicates a process as in

> - He gets down from the ladder.
> - He gets defeated in the fight
> - He gets married.

It is often part of a fixed phrase.

There are other ways to use "gets", of course. But "He gets awake" is not really one of them.

By the way if one uses the regular past form: "He gets waked" it probably means that he is dead and people gather to eat, droink, and talk in the room where his body is laid out. See ["Wake"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_(ceremony)) and ["Finnegan's Wake"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnegan%27s_Wake_)

Comment: Why can we say "He gets mad" or "He gets chilled" but not "He gets awake"? I started writing out an answer and got stuck at that point. I'm not sure if "awake" is just an exception to be learned or if there's an underlying rule.

Comment: @randomhead I fear that this is one of many cases where there is no clear logical rule. But in "he gets mad" "gets" means "becomes" not "remains". The use of "-ed" forms like ';"he gets chilled", "he get awakened", or "he gets fired", "he gets listed" seems ok, and again theer "gets" means "becomes".  whule "He gets beat" is wrong, should be "beaten". In fact I can't think of a valid "He gets X" where "gets" means "remains".

Comment: Thank you randomhead and David Siegel.